# django-smart-selects not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-smart-selects

I want to have chained foreign key in my django-admin and thus I am using django-smart-selects.
I have followed the documentation properly

1. Install django-smart-selects
2. Add it in installed_apps in settings.py
3. Add this line in my base urls.py

```
       url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

4. changed my model accordingly:

```
class AddressModel(BaseModel):
    country = models.ForeignKey(CountryModel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    state = ChainedForeignKey(StateModel, chained_field=country, chained_model_field=country,
                              null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

and added this to my setting.py

```
JQUERY_URL = True
```

But everytime I try to create an address from admin, I get this error:-

if path.startswith(('http://', 'https://', '/')):
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use **USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True** instead of **JQUERY_URL = True** in your settings.py

Answer (score 1):

Use **USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True**
and **JQUERY_URL = False**

- Add this in your html

```
        <script src="/static/smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/smart-selects/admin/js/bindfields.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

on the terminal entered 'show static files' then I got two static folders. Django automatically made a smart selectors folder, then I copied the smart selector's folder and pasted it into my only created static file, then resolved all my problems. Thank you.

```
show static files
```